# Python: Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have installed Tesseract 3.05 on my Windows 10.
I am trying to perform `image_to_string()` operation on a given image.

The function isn't able to locate the `tessdata` folder.
I have even added `TESSDATA_PREFIX` under the environment variables with path leading to `tessdata` folder which is present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`.

`tessdata` contains `eng.traineddata` and it still can't read it.

Error is as below:

```
File "ocr.py", line 38, in <module>
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
File "C:\Users\skuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
  return run_and_get_output(*args)
File "C:\Users\skuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
  run_tesseract(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\skuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 178, in run_tesseract
  raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

Is the mix in the backward slash (windows 10 default) and forward slash(linux style) the problem here 
or is it something else? Can someone please help me out? I am still a beginner with Tesseract.

Comment: Hi Sourav
am also facing the same issue are you able to resolve the issue you faced. if so can you please share the resolution of it

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please let me know if you are able to resolve this.

Comment: same issure here.
Did someone fix it? @PavanKumar

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya: after adding the environment variable did u restart ur machine.?

Comment: @PavanKumar thank you for getting back. I did not have to actually. I uninstalled the verion 4 and downloaded and installed 5.0 alpha from: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki . It worked right away after this. No environment variables and stuffs.